# jquery toggleClass menu doesn't work on first click

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggleclass

on my Demo, I add and remove the class Selected. If I click through the links and then click again the
**OPEN FORM** the toggleClass doesn't work on a first click. why? what am I missing?

Basically by clicking `OPEN FORM` I should `addClass('selected')` and `toggleClass('open')` .

Please see my Demo, and click the links.

http://jsfiddle.net/y8oL13Ld/

my js:

```
$('.cta a').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $('.cta a').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');

    if ($('.Contact-form.selected').is(':visible')) {

        $('.cloned-contactform').addClass('open');
    } else {
        $('.cloned-contactform').removeClass('open');
    }

    $('.Contact-form.selected').bind('click', function () {
        $('.cloned-contactform').toggleClass('open');

    });


});
```

html:

```
<ul class="cta">
    <li><a href="#" class="Contact-form">OPEN FORM</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="Globe">LINK</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="Search">LINK</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="cloned-contactform">
    <div class="contactform"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: It apparently works on your `jsFiddle`?

Comment: if you click the others then again OPEN FORM, doesn't toggle on first click

Comment: What do you mean by "click again the
OPEN FORM"? Your fiddle has no such text. Is this what you're after http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/goeov4t6/?

Comment: You have just one link with `class` `Contact-form`.

Comment: here you go sorry, http://jsfiddle.net/y8oL13Ld/

Comment: Do you mean 1) open the form, 2) Click a link (the form closes), 3) click open and it won't open for 2 clicks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you look for soemthing like this?: http://jsfiddle.net/y8oL13Ld/1/

```
$('.Contact-form').on('click', function() {
    $('.cta a').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');

    if ($('.cloned-contactform').is(':visible')) {
        $('.cloned-contactform').removeClass('open');
        $('.cloned-contactform').hide();
    }
    else {
        $('.cloned-contactform').addClass('open');
        $('.cloned-contactform').show(); 
    }
});
```

explanation: the OP js is a little convoluted in the logic. although i'm not exactly sure exactly the functionality of what the OP wants, i ripped all unnecessary js and fulfilled the requirements that:

- clicking OPEN FORUM adds the class selected to the anchor (and removes selected from other links if they have class selected)
- the div cloned-contactform's class open gets toggled
- the div cloned-contactform's visibility toggles

EDIT: due to the refined definition of requirements i updated the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/y8oL13Ld/2/

the following jquery handles the fact that if the other links are clicked, it closes the div cloned-contactform and are selected.

```
$('.Globe, .Search').on('click', function() {
    $('.cta a').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
    $('.cloned-contactform').removeClass('open');
    $('.cloned-contactform').hide();        
});
```

FINAL EDIT: hopefully lol, due to scope change.  http://jsfiddle.net/y8oL13Ld/4/

```
$('.cta a').on('click', function(){
    // if clicked contact link
    if ($(this).hasClass('contact')) {
        // if already selected
        if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
            // toggle
            $('.contact-div').removeClass('open');
            $(this).removeClass('selected');
        }
        // if not already selected
        else {
            // remove selected and open classes from all others
            $('.cta a').removeClass('selected');
            $('.section').removeClass('open');
            // apply selected and open classes to this
            $('.contact-div').addClass('open');
            $(this).addClass('selected');
        }
    }
 });
```

and i switched the html structure a little:

```
<div class="contact-div section">contact div</div>
<div class="global-div section" style="background:gray;">global div</div>
<div class="search-div section" style="background:lightgray;"> search div</div>
```

Comment: What did you change and why? A little explanation would be helpful.

Comment: @indubitablee http://jsfiddle.net/y1y4ee76/1/ please have a look at mine, if you click the anchors, works fine, but when clicking back OPEN FORUM, it works alternate.

Comment: @user3699998 thank you, i'm aware of the alternate clicks, which isnt the functionality you wanted. so i modified to the js so as to work(have a look)...is there something different you wanted? if so, please tell us so we could better help you

Comment: @user3699998 do you want all the other links to close the div cloned-contactform? (is that the difference you want to happen?) if you could clearly explain the whole functionality of each of the links, that would be helpful

Comment: @indubitablee yes, the other links should close the "cloned-contactform" and become selected. then by clicking back OPEN FORUM, becomes selected and gives the "cloned-contactform" a "open" class, could u help please?

Comment: @user3699998 see my edited answer, i posted a new jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/y8oL13Ld/2/

Comment: @indubitablee that's good thanks. I was trying to achieve something like that for each link. so each link opens up a different hidden div

Comment: @user3699998 is my answer acceptable? and ah, haha, if you stated your previous comment in your question, i could have helped you a lot quicker.

Comment: sorry if it took me a while to explain, is a bit complicated. Anyway, is acceptable, sure, but could u help me with this please?

Comment: sure, give me a bit and i'll have it

Comment: @user3699998, updated the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/y8oL13Ld/4/.  if its to your liking, please accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

Kinda guessing here, but it looks like you're making a nav and clicking a link in it shows a certain div. *If* that's what you're trying to achieve maybe some refactoring advice could be this:

Have a div for each of your sections

```
<div class="section contact-form">Form Stuff</div>
<div class="section globe">Globe Stuff</div>
<div class="section search">Search Stuff</div>
```

Then your links could be like:

```
<li><a href="#" data-section="contact-form">OPEN FORM</a></li>
<li><a href="#" data-section="globe">LINK</a></li>
<li><a href="#" data-section="search">LINK</a></li>
```

Then your javascript code is ambiguous to which link you clicked:

```
$('a').click(function(){
  // Grab the value of data-section
  var selected = $(this).data('section')
  $('.section').hide()
  // Show the corresponding div
  $("'."+ selected + "'").show()
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4brfejw5/

Comment: looks look thaks. http://jsfiddle.net/4brfejw5/1/ this what I'd like to achieve, but is not working properly

Comment: What are your requirements?